# nginx match location after prefix

Tags: nginx

The problem is that nginx is matching paths correctly on www.example.com/en/
or www.example.com/pl/ but not www.example.com/en/something/. If I go to www.example.com/en/something/ then I get "Welcome to nginx!" page. 
When I visit www.example.com/en/ then do action that redirects to www.example.com/en/something/ - this scenario works.

I tried locations: '/en', '^~ /en'.

What's going on?

my nginx.conf is looking like this:

```
server {

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name xxx; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html/en;
          index index.html index.htm;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /en/ {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /pl/ {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

Comment: In order for others to help you, you need to be more specific on what the meaning of "same result", and what do you means "not works". Every location directive you listed have a root of `/usr/share/nginx/html`, then why you have `root /var/www/html` on top? what exactly is your directory structure?

Comment: I edited question a bit. Also, this nginx is a bit messy, I will remove unused code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current configuration, you use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;`.

Ignoring the redundant `=404` on the end, if the file is not found, the file located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` will be returned. And that file probably contains "Welcome to nginx!".

All parameters of the `try_files` directive are like URIs, and the correct URI for the `/en/` index page is `/en/index.html`.

For example:

```
index index.html index.htm;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location /en/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.html;
}
location /pl/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /pl/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it work. Your answer should works as well (and it is better than I have). I pasted cfg in comment to my next question in so.